# Hypothesis Testing for Paired Count Data

Tags: hypothesis-testing, count-data, paired-data, zero-inflation, pre-post-comparison

I have the following data:

For a group of patients, the number of hospital visits in a 6 month period both before and after receiving a treatment has been measured. I wish to demonstrate that the treatment is effective by showing that the number of hospital visits after receiving the treatment is significantly lower than the number of visits before receiving it by using a hypothesis test.

I don't believe I can use a paired t-test as the data is not normally distributed. Is a paired Wilcoxon test the best I can do here? I have read about the possibility of using a Poisson or Negative Binomial GLM - I have briefly used GLMs before but I am unsure about how to apply them to perform a hypothesis test of this nature.

As a further question - my data is quite zero-inflated. Can I do better by applying an appropriate zero-inflated model such as a zero-inflated Poisson regression?

Comment: The question seems problematic. Did everyone have at least one visit before treatment? If so, then many of them could have zero visits after treatment just randomly. What were the average numbers of visits before and after?